AWS CDK Role with preferred_role claim in tokens
While creating an identity pool through the AWS console, at one point you're prompted to select how cognito will identify the user roles. Like so:

How do you accomplish the same in Python CDK?? (I mean how do you select the third option: "preferred_role claim") Bonus points for also showing where it is in the docs as I cannot find it.
Thanks
